# PDO bind param loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I saw the similar question, however it does not help me. I have this here PHP:

```
//looping array contains one value - below line not part of code, just for to expmplify
var_dump($categoriesBind) -> array(1) { [0]=> &string(10) "healthcare" } 


$sqlPS->bindParam(':belonging', $_GET['belonging']);
$sqlPS->bindParam(':title', $_GET['title']);
//variable number of parameters
for ($i = 0; $i < count($categoriesBind); $i++){
    $sqlPS->bindParam(':'.$categoriesBind[$i], $categoriesBind[$i]);
}
```

The resulting string from that is this:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_article 
WHERE belonging = ':belonging' 
AND blog_article.title != ':title' 
AND category LIKE '%:healthcare%' 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(':healthcare',category) desc LIMIT 0,3
```

That returns `array(0){}`

However if i run the query with the filled in parameters manually, it runs fine and returns results. **The ':belonging' and ':title' parameters bind fine**, the problem is in the other binding interpretations and i can not, for the life of me, figure out what's going on.

**UPDATE: upon further testing this is what fails `'%:healthcare%'`. The parameters do not bind inside the LIKE syntax.**

If more info is needed, please ask.

Comment: You need to change `healthcare` to `%healthcare%` in the original array.

Comment: Well, in the DB the column contains  `'healthcare'`, no percentages. Will it match still?

Comment: Right, got it. Will mark for closure. Thank you.

Comment: The percentage signs are wildcards, which means that it matches any string. So if you have `World's best healthcare system` and you do `WHERE column LIKE `%healthcare%` it will match that row. The percentage signs are not in the original value.